# How to upload an snapshopt of a table with SyncOrchestrator?

Tags: sql, azure, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I need to upload some tables to Azure. But upload without sync. Just delete the Azure data and upload the Local one.

I found some examples to do it with the SyncAgent, but also I read that the [SyncOrchestrator is the "new SyncAgent"](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6cee0560-2ef2-44fc-a26b-2f1880c29781/what-is-the-difference-between-the-syncorchestrator-and-the-syncagent?forum=syncgeneral) so I need an example for upload tables snapshots from Local SQL Server to SQL Azure with SyncOrchestrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshots are no supported in syncorchestrator and in syncagent is only supported for SQL compact databases.

If you want to simulate snapshots, provision both databases, then sync and deprovision and repeat the same thing every time you want to sync.

Comment: Thanks @JuneT. We alredy did what you tell us but, as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052917/how-use-sync-framework-to-sync-tables-that-are-recreated-with-mostly-the-same-da/21070140?iemail=1&noredirect=1#21070140) this process is very slowly.

Comment: Maybe you can help us with any idea for this situation:
We need to sync a Local SQL2005 in Win2003 Server with Azure.
We are using SyncOrchestator and its very cool to sync some tables. But the process is very slow with other tables that are recreated. 
We can´t use SychOrchestator because the process is very slow. 
We can´t use SychAgent because it only works with SQL CE. 
We can´t use Integration Services because we have SQL 2005. We can´t  use Azure Sync Agent because we have Win2003. And we need an automatic process to move tables from our local server to Azure.... Any idea?

Comment: Hi JuneT, could you please clarify your statement "snapshots are not supported in SyncOrchestrator"? I have just started using snapshots in combination with SyncOrchestrator and it seems to be fine.